# Gmail сервер не может обработать запрос, ошибка 400. Проблема с запросом или куками? Как решить эту проблему? Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, gmail, webdriver

```
import undetected_chromedriver
import time
import random
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
def parseCookieFile(cookiefile):
    cookies = {}
    with open(cookiefile, 'r') as fp:
        content = fp.read()

    lines = content.strip().split('\n')
    for line in lines:
        if not line.startswith('#'):
            fields = line.strip().split('\t')
            if len(fields) >= 7:
                name = fields[5]
                value = fields[6]
                cookies[name] = value

    return cookies

a = parseCookieFile('s.txt')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    options = undetected_chromedriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--user-data-dir')
    options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
    options.add_argument('--disable-web-security')
    options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/116.0")
    options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")

    browser = undetected_chromedriver.Chrome(options=options,
                                             driver_executable_path=my_path)
    browser.delete_all_cookies()
    browser.get('https://www.google.com/')
    browser.implicitly_wait(15)
    time.sleep(10)
    browser.get('https://accounts.google.com/v3/signin/identifier?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&ec=GAZAmgQ&hl=ru&ifkv=AVQVeyy2_AjsoEWxgealPJCDMF4_tYlRJ5ViuAoO6vYzn-W8gF63iAdSni_8MqneegEum1TR8UxflA&passive=true&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin&dsh=S370086579%3A1697312770591432&theme=glif')
    time.sleep(10)
    for name, value in a.items():
        browser.add_cookie({'name': name, 'value': value})
    time.sleep(10)
    browser.get('https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser/signinchooser?service=mail&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=AccountChooser&theme=glif')
    time.sleep(10)
    browser.get('https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/')
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Есть куки в txt, я пытаюсь их добавлять в куки самого браузера и при переходе на страницу авторизации первой почты мне выдает ошибку Сервер не может обработать запрос из-за синтаксических ошибок. Ошибка 400

Comment: Но при этом, если я ввожу свой логин пароль всё отлично работает